# How to permanently disable QML debugger in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

Whenever I make a Qt project, the qmake command includes this parameter:

```
CONFIG += qml_debug
```

I never use QML and don't want to manually click three times and ignore the warning every time I generate a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Projects -> Build & Run -> Run Settings. There is an "Enable QML" setting, mine is disabled.

[image]

If not, I advise you to check Tools -> Options -> Build & Run, and Tools -> Options -> Debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me in a project. I just added this to the .pro file :

```
CONFIG -= qml_debug
```

It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To disable QML debugging in Qt Creator 12.0.1:

- Go to the menubar, Edit -> Preferences -> Build & Run -> Default Build Properties
- Choose "Disable" for the "QML debugging" setting.

[image: A GIF demonstrating where to find the setting in Qt Creator]

**Note:** For already-built projects, you need to delete the build folder and build again for this to take effect. Cleaning and rebuilding is not enough.